# Give a closure as a «class method pointer»?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, closures, function-pointers

Okay, that should be simple, basically the example below should have worked *(at least be compiled)*:

```
class Foo {
public:
    void DoNothing( void(Foo::*funcptr)() ){}
    void CallDoNothing();
};

void Foo::CallDoNothing(){
    auto closure = [this](){};
    DoNothing(closure);
}

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

But for some reason that triggers a compilation error

```
test.cpp: In member function ‘void Foo::CallDoNothing()’:
test.cpp:9:19: error: no matching function for call to ‘Foo::DoNothing(Foo::CallDoNothing()::__lambda0&)’
  DoNothing(closure);
                   ^
test.cpp:9:19: note: candidate is:
test.cpp:3:7: note: void Foo::DoNothing(void (Foo::*)())
  void DoNothing( void(Foo::*funcptr)() ){}
       ^
test.cpp:3:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Foo::CallDoNothing()::__lambda0’ to ‘void (Foo::*)()’
```

I am already even tried to cast: `DoNothing(reinterpret_cast< void(Foo::*funcptr)() >(closure));`, `DoNothing(( void(Foo::*funcptr)() )closure);`, plus some variations on this — these all just triggered a compilation errors!

Comment: Lambdas with captures cannot be converted to function pointers, let alone member function pointers.

Comment: @user657267 well, if this indeed so, this is very sad… Okay, then how do I declare an argument that accepts a closure (i.e. a lambda with a local variables captured)?

Comment: `std::function<void()>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you think that a lambda function can be assigned to a member function pointer? A lambda function is of some anonymous type. It is assignable to function pointers only if it has an empty capture, but even that is not compatible with a member function pointer as in your example.

You can use `std::function<void ()>` or make `DoNothing` a template function.

Comment: I am thinking so exactly because a lambda without a closures could be implicitly casted by a compiler to a simple function pointer. Next we ask ourself: what is the difference of a closure with this simple lambda? Next we remember that a class function pointer are differ from an usual ones since these implicitly accepts «this» as the first argument. So, obviously, a closure could be casted only to a «class method pointer». It is a deduction :Ь

Comment: @Hi-Angel If you know that only a lambda function with empty capture can be assigned to a function pointer, and the language does not define anything for lambdas with captures, I find it brave to assume that there is a relationship between a lambda with this as the capture and a member function pointer. It sounds reasonable on a semantic level, but the compiler has to adhere to the language definition. As this does not say it, I do not see why you should assume that it works. Logic arguments and language standards are sometimes very different :-)

Comment: Well, tbh I didn't knew that the language standard doesn't define any cast for a closures, that's why I tried to write a lisp-like function in a real program, and, finally, asked this question ☺

Comment: @Hi-Angel You can lookup the latest draft of the standard at isocpp.org. It is not very readable, but good as a reference. You could also ask in one of the forums on that side why the conversion is omitted, maybe you can even convince them to consider it for a future standard.